# Variable needs to be declared final

Tags: java, android, variables, button, final

I am trying to have a score variable go up by one every time a button is clicked. The problem is I must declare the score variable outside of the onClick otherwise it will always be set to 0. Also, I cannot declare the variable final because I am modifying the variable. Here is the code.

```
    int score = 0;

    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            score++;

            scoreLabel.setText(String.valueOf(score));
```

Comment: Make it class member variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the var score is scoped in a method, move that and declare **score** as a class variable.

Comment: Move the score variable as a "Global" variable or class variable....

Comment: Yes I know, but I can't do it unless I wait 10 minutes.

Comment: I just changed the score variable to be public.

Comment: Not the best idea. See Answer posted by @Mathews Mathai.

Answer (score 2):

The ideal solution would be to make the variable `static` and make it the member of the outer class. Making it `static` means, all the objects of the class will share a single copy of the variable and the value will remain same everywhere.

Declare `static int score;` in the outer class.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use static variables, you could declare the score in the outer class (private int score;), then initialize it in the constructor. This will give it the right scope to be accessed!

Answer (score 0):

You can use MutableInt which as its name indicates is a mutable integer. This class is provided in the apache commons. 
This way you can keep the variable local and final.

Hope this helps